# What are some applications of Kolmogorov's criterion for projection onto convex sets?

Tags: optimization, projection

**Kolmogorov's criterion for projection onto convex sets:** Let x be a vector in a Hilbert space H and let C be a closed convex subset of H. Then there exists a unique vector $c_0 \in C$ such that $\|x−c_0\| ≤ \|x−c\|$ for all $c \in C$. Moreover, a necessary and sufficient condition that $c_0$ be the unique minimizing vector is that $\langle x − c_0, c − c_0 \rangle \leq 0$ for all $c \in C$.

The above criterion provides a geometric characterization for finding the projection from an external point to a closed-convex set. Are there any practical scenarios that require using this criterion to find the projection instead of using the optimization framework given by $c_0=\text{arg}\min_{c\in C}\|c−x\|$?

Comment: If $C$ is the convex hull of a finite number of points, then it gives an easy to compute optimlity criterion for minimising.

Comment: Yes in such a scenario the geometric characterization seems advantageous. But are there any other situations pertaining to general convex sets (with an uncountable number of points) that require this characterization?

Comment: The question is a bit too general to give a solid answer. The criterion can be generalised to minimising convex $f$ as well.

Comment: Yes, which leads to a semi-infinite program, as all points in the set need to satisfy the criterion. Which, in general, is a much more difficult problem to solve than the convex optimization problem that we get via the distance characterization $c_o = \text{arg}\min_{c\in C}\|c−x\|$.  So would this mean that we may treat the Kolmogorov criterion just as an observation with no practical application?

Comment: That is a bit of a leap in terms of conclusions. The Frank Wolfe algorithm, and derivatives, rely on such a characterisation in a fundamental way.